# LCS (Longest Common Subsequence) algorithm complexity

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have written a java code for calculating LCS. If you find bugs, let me know please.

```
public class Main {

    public static void calcLSC(int X[], int i, int Y[], int j) {

        int c[] [] = new int[i + 1] [j + 1];
        for (int a = 0; a < i + 1; ++a)
            for ( int b = 0; b < j + 1; ++ b)
                c[a][b] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        LCS(X, i, Y, j, c);
        print(X, i, j, c);
    }

    private static int LCS(int[] X, int i, int Y[], int j, int c[][]) {
        if (c[i][j] > Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return c[i][j];
        }
        else if(i == 0 || j == 0) 
            c[i][j] = 0;
        else if(X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]) 
            c[i][j] = 1 + LCS(X,i-1, Y, j-1, c);
        else if(X[i - 1] != Y[j - 1])
            c[i][j] = Math.max(LCS(X,i-1, Y, j, c), LCS(X,i, Y, j-1, c));
        return c[i][j];
    }

    private static void print(int X[],int i, int j, int c[][]) {
        if(i == 0 || j == 0) return;
        else if (c[i - 1][j - 1] >= c [i] [j - 1] && c[i - 1][j - 1] >= c [i - 1] [j] && c[i ][j] - c[i - 1][j - 1] == 1) {
            print(X, i - 1, j - 1, c);
            System.out.print(X[i - 1] + " ");
        }
        else if (c[i - 1][j] >= c[i][j -1])
            print(X, i -1, j, c);
        else 
            print(X, i, j - 1, c);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,5,7,8,9,0};
        int a2[] = {11,22,33,3,44,55,66,5,77,88,5, 99, 111, 222, 7, 333, 444, 555, 666};
        calcLSC(a1, a1.length, a2, a2.length);
    }
}
```

This is ascending recursive implementation with memoization. It's complexity should be O(mn), where m, n - lengths of input sequences.

Comment: Something for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are the people with time and aim to review. Mayby: `int[][] c` is more java like, the other form is for C compatibility. BTW there is a very dense solution with just one array indexed by length.

Comment: Before you do, one question. **is it working as intended**? If so, feel free to bring it over.

Comment: Since LCS is NP-hard, if you did it in P, you should apply for a Turing Award ;-). However, your `LCS()` function has a worst-case recursive call where you recurse with essentially  `n - 1`  (at `Math.max()`). That makes this `O(n!)`.

Comment: No, in Cormen "Introduction to algorithms" there is a O(mn)  ascending implementation without recursion. Using dynamic-programming allows to reduce complexity to O(mn). My implementation is  O(mn) too, but it is descending recursive implementation - it is one of the task in Cormen book. My solution calculates each subtask only once, and stores calculated value in matrix, and when during recursive call next time same subtask occurs, implementation does not calculate it again, it returns ready answer from matrix. Matrix size = n * m, each subtask is calculated only once, so O(n) = mn